# How can i recreate a spreadsheet or sharepoint datasheet view on a website?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sharepoint, spreadsheet

I am trying to migrate users off of a sharepoint solution into a website + SQL backend.  The one thing is that everyone seems to like the sharepoint view and the data sheet view for editing and managing information.

what is the best spreadsheet / access data editing solution.  are there any third party asp.net mvc widgets that are good alternatives

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Telerik's Grid for MVC](http://www.telerik.com/products/aspnet-mvc/grid.aspx) is supposed to be good, but you may want to consider an alternative to the traditional grid UI experience.

The MVC paradigm does not explicitly define how you should do things- that's one of it's many strengths. But it does however *encourage* users into certain directions: testing; maintainability; separation of concerns (logical isolation); design patterns; user experience; user centered design; etc, etc. With this in mind is there an alternative to a grid that you may be able to use? Repeating elements? In line editing (think Facebook comments)? Don't show all items, just the top 10 most relevant to the user? [Live Search](http://jobs.37signals.com/) to filter without all the options? Maybe you can create a better experience for the users without a grid, and now that you're going to use MVC, this is the best time to do it.

See how easy it is to turn something sad looking

[image]

..into something happy

[image]

Keys ideas:

- Remove the fluff
- Some things are obvious
- Search is capable of figuring out stuff by itself
- and the popular: Less is more

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to craft this response. Very well done!

Answer (score 1):

Telerik (good MVC support) or [JqGrid](http://www.trirand.com/blog/) (free) are very nice. If you want a more spreadsheet approach, have a look at [jquery.sheet](http://jqueryplugins.weebly.com/jquerysheet.html).

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at Matt Berseth's blog, he has done some amazing stuff with the listview control (and other ASP.NET cotrols).

The following link might be specificly to what you are looking for:

[Bulk Inserting Data with the ListView Control](http://mattberseth.com/blog/2008/05/bulk_inserting_data_with_the_l.html)

and a example:

[Bulk Inserting Data with the ListView Control - Live Example](http://mattberseth2.com/demo/Default.aspx?Name=Bulk+Inserting+Data+with+the+ListView+Control&Filter=All)

Answer (score 0):

[This one](http://www.aspboy.com/Categories/GridArticles/Excel_Like_GridView.aspx) has some limitations (only works in IE), but some commenters say it meets their needs. it "a Grid which has resizable columns, a Grid which has resizable rows, a Grid which has editable cells, a Grid whose cells can be navigated by using the arrow keys and the Tab key, a focussed cell in the Grid which responds to the key strokes when a user starts typing."

And here's [another one](http://www.wherecanibuyit.co.uk/ASP/fully_editable_gridview.html) that might suit your needs, a "fully editable GridView".

Answer (score 0):

You may want to have a look at Grapecity Spread ,it is a very good spreadsheet component and is really easy to use and therefore allows easy management and editing information .Spread also supports MVC along with the Razor view engine . You can read more about this here :

http://www.gcpowertools.info/2011/12/using-grapecity-spread-for-net-with-mvc.html